# Delphi - How do I ensure proper and reliable termination of thread without memory loss

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

**Situation:** I have a program that initiates a thread to run continuously in the background. When I terminate this thread, I intermittently get a Runtime Error 204 (Invalid Pointer) and memory leaks.

**Code to Create the Thread** (it is created in an object TJEList that has a method OnLJ2DOSyncThreadNotification to be called on notification that performs some actions using some of the TStringList objects in the thread):

```
  FLJ2DOSyncThread:=TLJ2DOSyncThread.Create (True);
  FLJ2DOSyncThread.NotifyEvent:=OnLJ2DOSyncThreadNotification;
  FLJ2DOSyncThread.Start;
```

**The Thread's `Execute` code:**

```
  FreeOnTerminate:=True;

  //I create 5 StringList objects here - they are declared as private variables in the Thread

  try
    while Not Terminated do
    begin
      //Perform operation (which internally also checks for Terminated)
      if Terminated then
        Break;
      //Perform different operation (which internally also checks for Terminated)
      if Terminated then
        Break;
      //Perform different operation (which internally also checks for Terminated)
      if Terminated then
        Break;
      //etc...
      Sleep (1500);
    end;
  finally
    //I FreeAndNil(...) all the TStringlist objects
  end;
```

For good measure (although likely redundant), I also have a destructor in the thread that does:

```
 if Assigned (TStringList object) then FreeAndNil (TStringList object);
```

for all of the TStringList objects that were created (and then calls `inherited;`).

**My code to stop the thread is:**

```
  if Assigned(FLJ2DOSyncThread) then
    if FLJ2DOSyncThread.Started then
      FLJ2DOSyncThread.Terminate;
```

I call the code to stop the thread from the destructor of the TJEList object (which gets called on the closure of the main form of the application).

**The Issue:**
Sometimes, the program terminates cleanly (no memory leaks, or error messages). Other times, I get the following error message and memory leak (for what it's worth, the memory leak message appears before the Runtime error message):

[image]

[image]

**My Question:** How do I ensure that the thread **always** reliably terminates (and therefore gets freed)? Any help and/or guidance would be most appreciated!

**UPDATE 20170310 5.08pm HKT: Including the code for MCVE as requested**

**Program Code:**

```
program ThreadIssueMCVE;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  frmMain in 'frmMain.pas' {fMain},
  MyList in 'MyList.pas',
  MyThread in 'MyThread.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
  {$IFDEF DEBUG}
  System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:=true;
  {$ENDIF}
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TfMain, fMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**Main Form Code:**

```
unit frmMain;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, MyList,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TfMain = class(TForm)
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FMyList: TMyList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  fMain: TfMain;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TfMain.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  FreeAndNil(FMyList);
end;

procedure TfMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMyList:=TMyList.Create;
end;

end.
```

**MyList Code:**

```
unit MyList;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, MyThread;


type
  TMyList = Class (TObject)
  private
    FSomeList: TStringList;
    FMyThread: TMyThread;
  protected
    procedure OnMyThreadNotification (Sender: TObject);
    procedure OnMyThreadTerminate (Sender: TObject);
    procedure ActOnThreadResults (AList: TStringList);
  public
    procedure InitMyThread;
    procedure StopMyThread;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  property
    SomeList: TStringList read FSomeList;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyList }

constructor TMyList.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;

  FSomeList:=TStringList.Create;

  InitMyThread;
end;

destructor TMyList.Destroy;
begin
  StopMyThread;

  FreeAndNil(FSomeList);

  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TMyList.ActOnThreadResults (AList: TStringList);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i:= 0 to AList.Count-1 do
  begin
    if FMyThread.CheckTerminated then
      exit;
    FSomeList.Add(AList.Strings[i]);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyList.InitMyThread;
begin
  FMyThread:=TMyThread.Create (True);
  FMyThread.NotifyEvent:=OnMyThreadNotification;
  FMyThread.OnTerminate:=OnMyThreadTerminate;
  FMyThread.Start;
end;

procedure TMyList.OnMyThreadNotification(Sender: TObject);
var
  fullList: TStringList;
begin
  if (FMyThread.FList4.Count>0) or (FMyThread.FList5.Count>0) then
  begin
    fullList:=TStringList.Create;
    try
      fullList.Text:=FMyThread.FList4.Text + FMyThread.FList5.Text;
      ActOnThreadResults(fullList);
    finally
      FreeAndNil (fullList);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyList.OnMyThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(FMyThread);
end;

procedure TMyList.StopMyThread;
begin
  FMyThread.Terminate;
end;

end.
```

**MyThread Code:**

```
unit MyThread;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils;

type
  TMyThread = Class (TThread)
  private
    FLastRun: TDateTime;
    FList1: TStringList;
    FList2: TStringList;
    procedure SomeProcess;
    procedure SomeOtherProcess;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    NotifyEvent: TNotifyEvent;
    FList3: TStringList;
    FList4: TStringList;
    FList5: TStringList;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  End;

implementation

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FList1);
  FreeAndNil(FList2);
  FreeAndNil(FList3);
  FreeAndNil(FList4);
  FreeAndNil(FList5);

  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.SomeOtherProcess;
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 1000000 do
  begin
    if Terminated then
      break;

    //do some stuff here
    FList5.Add(i.ToString);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.SomeProcess;
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 1000000 do
  begin
    if Terminated then
      break;

    //do some stuff here
    FList4.Add(i.ToString);
  end;
end;


procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  boolCheck: Boolean;
begin
  NameThreadForDebugging('Thread with issues');
  FreeOnTerminate:=False;

  FList1:=TStringList.Create;
  FList2:=TStringList.Create;
  FList3:=TStringList.Create;
  FList4:=TStringList.Create;
  FList5:=TStringList.Create;
  FLastRun:=Now; //i get this from an ini file normally

  try
    while Not Terminated do
    begin
      if Terminated then
        Break;
      FList1.Clear;
      FList2.Clear;
      FList3.Clear;
      FList4.Clear;
      FList5.Clear;

      if Terminated then
        Break;
      SomeProcess;
      if Terminated then
        Break;
      SomeOtherProcess;
      if Terminated then
        Break;
      SomeProcess;
      if Terminated then
        Break;
      SomeOtherProcess;
      if Terminated then
        Break;
      SomeProcess;
      if Terminated then
        Break;

      if (FList4.Count>0) OR (FList5.Count>0) then
        boolCheck:=True;

      if Terminated then
        Break;
      if boolCheck then
        NotifyEvent(Self);

      if Terminated then
        Break;
      Sleep (2000);

      if Terminated then
        Break;

      FLastRun:=Now;      //i save to ini file as well
    end;
  finally
    //i save to ini file the last run
    FreeAndNil(FList1);
    FreeAndNil(FList2);
    FreeAndNil(FList3);
    FreeAndNil(FList4);
    FreeAndNil(FList5);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Maybe the problem can be related to not wait for the thread finalization. So try calling the `WaitFor` method like this  `FLJ2DOSyncThread.WaitFor;` after of the `Terminate` call.

Comment: @RRUZ Thanks for the comment. I had considered this and had tried adding the WaitFor but when I do so I get the following error: "<ApplicationName.exe> raised exception class EThread with message 'Thread Error: The handle is invalid (6)'."

Comment: @Rohit you are using `FreeOnTerminate=True`, so it is not safe to use `WaitFor()`, doing so is a race condition that can cause crashes. `FreeOnTerminate` should only be used for start-and-forget threads. This is not that kind of situation, so get rid of `FreeOnTerminate` and explicitly `Free` the thread when you are done using it

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I am indeed using `FreeOnTerminate=True`. As such, my code does not include the `WaitFor()` call. I just tried it to see if that was the issue (and got the error mentioned above).

Comment: Someone downvoted my question. I would love some feedback as to why. Don't want to contest it or anything but genuinely want to understand what I can do to improve the way the question is framed...

Comment: We need a MCVE really

Comment: Could the runtime errror happen because the program was closed while doing the Sleep(1500)? On return from Sleep, and when terminating, is there still a program to return to?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have created a MCVE - but since it is an MCVE I have removed a lot of the processing that happens in the TJEList as well as the TLJ2DOsyncThread. What is the best way to provide that? Should I just edit my question and add it there?

Comment: Yes, that should appear in the question

Comment: Thank you for the guidance @DavidHeffernan. I have included the MCVE in the question. Would appreciate any further insights...

Comment: The problem is that you hold a reference to the thread and set `FreeOnTerminate` to `True`. You make no attempt to clear that reference when the thread object is destroyed. That was explained in Remy's comment.

Comment: If you simply must use `FreeOnTerminate` (and so many people do so for no good reason and fall into the same trap you have found) then you have to add on `OnTerminate` event handler and clear your reference there.

Comment: And please please please stop testing `Assigned` before calling `Free`. `Free` already tests whether or not the object is assigned and so your code adds needless clutter.

Comment: Thank you @DavidHeffernan. I did not notice that @RemyLebeau had edited his comment for further clarity (my fault). That thought had however occurred to me and I had tried it out in my program (did not help). I have edited my MCVE and added in code for `OnTerminate` - but the issue persists - will update the MCVE code to reflect this. (Also - thanks for the guidance on code clarity related to Assigned/Free - I will ensure I address this in my program.)

Comment: I'm not going to attempt to run your code though because it is not minimal. There's still far too much clutter that we don't need to see.

Comment: I am sorry @DavidHeffernan - I was trying to show all the things that were happening in the code without writing out all the code (which is quite a lot). Appreciate everyone that has spent time on this (have been struggling with this for a few days now). If I figure out the issue I will post the response here...

Comment: I think I have solved the issue. To fix it, I changed the `FreeOnTerminate:=False` and in the code to Stop the thread, I included `WaitFor` and `Free`. Now it reliably and consistently kills the thread with no memory loss. I would like to give credit where it is due - @RRUZ, @RemyLebeau, @AndersJ and @DavidHeffernan all alluded to various aspects of this in their comments. In addition, @Dsm has also indicated this in their Answer - and correctly identified that the issue would be that the OnTerminate never gets called (causing memory leak). I am accepting @Dsm's answer but my thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race hazard. If you destroy your TMyList object before the thread terminates naturally, it can still call the notify event, but your object no longer exists (even though the thread still does). The simplest way I found to deal with this and stop memory leaks is to wait for the thread to terminate in the StopMyThread routine, and put the destruction of FMyThread into the destructor (as it stands OnTerminate is not called if you exit the application).

```
destructor TMyList.Destroy;
begin
  StopMyThread;


  FreeAndNil(FSomeList);
  FreeAndNil(FMyThread);

  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

and

```
procedure TMyList.StopMyThread;
begin
  FMyThread.Terminate;
  FMyThread.WaitFor;

end;
```

Comment: For the sake of clarity, here's what I did: (1) I changed `FreeOnTerminate` to False. (2) In the code to StopMyThread, I call `Terminate`, `WaitFor` and `Free` on the thread. This way, I am certain that the thread is terminated and freed whenever I call this procedure. Thanks again to everyone that spent time on helping me with this (personally, rather vexing) issue!